# Why are my input fields being stripped of the question mark?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Boolean field on one of my models:  `active?` ending in a question mark per Rails convention.  However, in my form, the question mark is removed from the HTML in the field name:

form:

```
<%= form_for @singer do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :active? %>
    <%= f.check_box :active?, :checked => true %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

HTML:

```
<form class="new_singer" id="new_singer" action="/singers" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
    <label for="singer_active">Active?</label>
    <input name="singer[active]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="singer[active]" id="singer_active" />
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Singer" data-disable-with="Create Singer" />
</form>
```

I can't find anything to suggest why this is happening.  If I open my console, I can create a new instance with `active?: true` without an issue.

Comment: `active?` is generally a helper method for boolean fields the actual column in your database is most likely `active` and thus the result.

Comment: No, it has the correct name in SQL developer, and creating something through the console works fine

Comment: Also I tested with other names for the field that were not used in the database and it worked fine (e.g., `f.check_box :foo`)

Comment: So the column is called `active?` that is unconventional. If you create a boolean field with a standard name like `active` rails will provide a helper method called `active?` but generally one does not call the column `active?`

Comment: Yeah I'm happy to change it--that seems like the obvious fix to this issue--but I'm still curious as to why that's happening

Comment: Is the form not working?

Comment: @hashrocket It throws out the `active?` param when processing the form, so it creates an object with all the other fields filled in but that one is blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rails convention is to use the `?` for **methods** that return a boolean value. You should not add a `?` to an attribute of a model. You should rename your attribute to active with a boolean value, like this: `active:boolean`. This will give you a method called `active?` that will return either true or false, depending on if the singer is active or not. Then your form should work.

Comment: I understand that; I'm asking where/how/why the question mark gets stripped

Comment: The question mark gets stripped because is shouldn't be there in the first place. Question marks are not valid in model attributes.

Comment: But it works in the console with `Singer.create(active?: true)`

Comment: I understand that, but it's not the rails convention to do it this way. If you change the attribute to active instead of active?, your form should work.